# PDF exists at URL; but download error

Tags: java, url, pdf

I have certain PDF files at URLs. I can view the files in the browser. 
Example URL: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC109492/pdf/pgen.1000626.pdf?tool=pmcentrez

But when I do

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC" + pmcid + "/pdf/pgen.1000626.pdf?tool=pmcentrez");

URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
InputStream urlIn = con.getInputStream();
```

I get `java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems like a forbidden access type of error, does the error occur when connecting (con = url.openConnection()) or after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can be a number of things. To name a few:

- you should authenticate
- you should set a `User-Agent` header
- you should set `Accept` header

Answer (score 1):

```
        URL url = new URL("http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC109492/pdf/pgen.1000626.pdf?tool=pmcentrez");


        //for pdf
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=report" + ".pdf");

        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

        BufferedOutputStream outs = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
        int len;
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        while ((len = stream.read(buf)) > 0) {
            outs.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        outs.close();
```